# How do I reload just the tableView section headers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm trying to get the `UITableView` section headers to change in background and text color when switching from one segment to another on a segmented control. To so so I need to reload the tableView data but I only want to reload the section headers. When using

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

It works but it also resets the rest of the data in the tableView which I'm not trying to do.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let stringForThemeHeader = "Theme Settings"
        let stringForToggleHeader = "Password Settings"
        if section == 0 {
            return stringForThemeHeader
        } else {
            return stringForToggleHeader
        }
    }
```

That's the code for setting up the titles.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        if darkModeSegmentedControlSwitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 || darkModeSegmentedControlSwitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.red
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }

    }
```

and that's the code to change the text and background. After a segment is selected it doesn't change unless the data of the entire tableView is reloaded using

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

So I just need to know how to reload only the section headers and my problem will be solved.

Comment: *"but it also resets the rest of the data in the tableView"* - then your data model isn't being kept up-to-date and `cellForRowAt` isn't doing its job of setting up each cell as needed.

Comment: Unrelated but you might find it helpful. Change `UIColor.init(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)` to `UIColor(white: 247.0/255, alpha: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually iterate the section headers.

```swift
for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
    guard let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: section) else {
        continue
    }
    // do something with the header
}
```

In case you have a lot of the sections you can iterate only visible headers. Just use `tableView.visibleCells` to collect the visible sections indexes.

Comment: The sections from `visibleCells` won't necessarily give you the visible headers. A header may be in view at the bottom but no cells from that section may be visible.

Comment: True, but easy to overcome.